ifdown: interface end0 not configured. RTNETLINK answers: File exists. ifup: interface end0 already configured when setting static and DHCP interface
In a device with Debian BookWorm 12.5, I want to enable and disable a static IP using a Node application at runtime. The /etc/network/interfaces is the following :
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

ifconfig gives the following output :
~# ifconfig
end0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.109.176  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.109.255
        inet6 fe80::7376:77ae:719e:249f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f8:dc:7a:3e:8d:bb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1155  bytes 392299 (383.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 519  bytes 84713 (82.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 344  bytes 23930 (23.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 344  bytes 23930 (23.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Trying to turn-down the end0 interface, I get the following :
~# ifdown end0
ifdown: interface end0 not configured

Then, I modify the /etc/network/interfaces as following :
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto end0
iface end0 inet static
  address 192.168.0.15
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.109.254

Trying to turn-up the interface with ifup end0, I get no error but the ifconfig output is the same as before. Trying again with ifup, I get the following :
~# ifup end0
ifup: interface end0 already configured

and ifconfig gives the same output as before.
I tried also to mess things up using ifconfig end0 down, service NetworkManager restart and service networking restart , but I continue to get undetermined behaviour, specially if I try to turn it down and up again when changing the interfaces file rolling back to dhcp configuration (i.e. without any reference to end0).
What am i missing?

I came up with the following resolutive sequence that can be repeated as many times as you want :
## turn down the interface **
~# ifdown end0 ; ip addr flush dev end0

** edit /etc/network/interfaces **

## reboot NetworkManager and turn the interface back up
~# service NetworkManager restart && ifup end0

where the static configuration looks like the following :
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto end0
iface end0 inet static
  address 192.168.0.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.109.254

and the DHCP configuration like the following :
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug end0
iface end0 inet dhcp

The only one-time change is the following : edit managed=true in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf as explicited here.
The great deal here is the following : when you add any reference of an interface like end0 in this file, then you force NetworkManager to handle the connection as decribed there, otherwise it will handle it differently. So, at boot time, networking service will turn the interface up using ifup end0, thus enabling the user to use ifdown and ifup to manipulate it at runtime. The only constriction is to reboot the NetworkManager service when the configuration changes.
